# Summing over all previous rows in large column efficiently

Tags: r

I have a large data set (>100,000 rows) and would like to create a new column that sums all previous values of another column.

For a simulated data set `test.data` with 100,000 rows and 2 columns, I create the new vector that sums the contents of column 2 with:

```
sapply(1:100000, function(x) sum(test.data[1:x[1],2]))
```

I append this vector to the `test.table` later with `cbind()` This is too slow, however. Is there a faster way to accomplish this, or be able to reference the vector that sapply is making in sapply so I can just update the cumulative sum instead of performing the whole calc again?

Comment: did you try merge()

Comment: Have you considered a creating it directly using cumsum?

Comment: Something like `test.data$sum <- cumsum(test.data[,2])`?

Comment: @MikeH. That works! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per my comment above it'll be faster if you do a direct assignment and use `cumsum` instead of `sapply` (cumsum was specifically built for what you want to do).

This should work:

`test.data$sum <- cumsum(test.data[, 2])`